# NodeJS net.Socket on("data") Data Not Flushing

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm receiving the same message on each line event.  I am receiving 1 event for each message.
Anyone know why.  It seems straight forward.

```
var rli = require("readline").createInterface({
    input: socket,
    output: socket,
    terminal: false
});
rli.on("line", handleServerMessage);
function handleServerMessage(msg) {
    console.log("Received msg from from server. msg=", msg);
}
```

Comment: The first response is correct for the first message I send.  But after that first message I make other requests and when I get the event back in NodeJS it is the same data.  I've checked the Server that the socket is connecting to with other socket applications and it is sending data correctly.

Comment: How are you defining `socket`?

Comment: Yes there is a lot of code and putting it all here isn't possible.

Comment: Is there a flush I can call?

Comment: Err this is so frustrating.  Telnetted to server and was able to get separate correct responses.  I have a printout just before my socket.write(); and it looks correct, also confirmed on the server side printout that it's getting the data correctly.  Sockets not clearing it's buffer or something.

Comment: I wrote a function to capture the arguments and it calls my callback with callback.apply(context, assembledArgs);  It wasn't rebuilding the args across callback calls.  

Sorry, the issue wasn't the socket but instead losing the arg.